# I add some column using laravel CMD. and then i want to migrate,rollback and rest getting error is Illuminate\Database\QueryException

Tags: php, laravel-7

> `$ php artisan migrate:fresh` is working fine
>
> Terminal

```
Me@kotai-sys MINGW64 /c/xampp/htdocs/laravel2
$ php artisan migrate:reset
Rolling back: 2020_07_28_115037_add_sex_to_test_table

   Illuminate\Database\QueryException

  SQLSTATE[42S02]: Base table or view not found: 1051 Unknown table 'laravel_start_2.sex' (SQL: drop table `sex`)

  at C:\xampp\htdocs\laravel2 \vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Database\Connection.php:671
 667|         // If an exception occurs when attempting to run a query, we'll format the error
 668|         // message to include the bindings with SQL, which will make this exception a
 669|         // lot more helpful to the developer instead of just the database's errors.
 670|         catch (Exception $e) {
>671|             throw new QueryException(
 672|                 $query, $this->prepareBindings($bindings), $e
 673|             );
 674|         }
 675|

  • A table was not found: You might have forgotten to run your migrations. You can run your migrations using `php artisan migrate`.
https://laravel.com/docs/master/migrations#running-migrations
```

> 1   C:\xampp\htdocs\laravel2 \vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Database\Connection.php:464
> PDOException::("SQLSTATE[42S02]: Base table or view not found: 1051 Unknown table 'laravel_start_2.sex'")

> 2   C:\xampp\htdocs\laravel2\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Database\Connection.php:464
> PDOStatement::execute()

**Here is the Migration file are**
[migrations php files](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mULXl.png)

```
$ php artisan migrate:status
+------+---------------------------------------------+-------+
| Ran? | Migration                                   | Batch |
+------+---------------------------------------------+-------+
| Yes  | 2014_10_12_000000_create_users_table        | 1     |
| Yes  | 2019_08_19_000000_create_failed_jobs_table  | 1     |
| Yes  | 2020_07_28_110554_create_test_table         | 1     |
| Yes  | 2020_07_28_114830_add_address_to_test_table | 1     |
| Yes  | 2020_07_28_115037_add_sex_to_test_table     | 1     |
+------+---------------------------------------------+-------+
```

Comment: `I add some column using laravel CMD` ??? Do you mean artisan command, because through artisan you can create and drop table, there is no command to add column using artisan, This table `'laravel_start_2.sex'` does not exist in your migration, so can you please take backup of your db and remove all tables and then run `php artisan migrate:refresh --seed` , i hope you have created migration file  for this `'laravel_start_2.sex'` table.

Comment: @Vipertecpro yes i add two column `address` and `sex` here `2020_07_28_114830_add_address_to_test_table ` and `2020_07_28_115037_add_sex_to_test_table`
This is the CMD --> `$ php artisan make:migration add_address_to_test_table --table=test` Right?